# How to add funds to Treasury?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, pallet-treasury

[image]

Someone please point me how to add funds in `Treasury`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is the treasury account ID - 5EYCAe5ijiYfyeZ2JJCGq56LmPyNRAKzpG4QkoQkkQNB5e6Z which is generated using the pallet-id of treasury so it is deterministic across all substrate based chains until the pallet-id is modified.

So a normal transfer to this account should answer your question.

To get account id for a pallet-id use the below command using subalfred tool.

```
subalfred key --type pallet --show-prefix 'py/trsry'
```

Comment: how to get account ID from palletId?

Comment: @Ganesh11 updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

What about doing a simple balance transfer to the account id of the treasury :)

E.g. [Polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/e0ed7e862c8c8b6c75eda1731c449543642176ef/runtime/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L648)

Comment: hey @Daan van der Plas [this is my configuration](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/a9ef41ac23a18df9bad800f9a5d4929daf082323/runtime/src/lib.rs#L718). I am confused how to transfer balance to the account id of the treasury? Where can I find treasury account id?

Comment: Just how you'd normally do a balance transfer. You could write a test and print it out and use [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/73c1388d6de8fe4b56463ba793393a0b2a2f25c8/frame/treasury/src/lib.rs#L247)